# How to stop nginx for windows?

Tags: windows, nginx, localhost

I can't stop the nginx server on windows. I've tried: `nginx -s stop`, `taskkill /if nginx.exe`, and end process via task manager, yet it's still running!

Answer (score 66):

Use `@taskkill /f /im nginx.exe` for this task.

Comment: @Normajean the `/f` switch does a force, which is sometimes needed. you might also need an elevated command prompt. otherwise, it is possible to sometimes get processes that cannot be killed. I'm not sure what causes it. I would also check that this isn't a service that needs stopping instead.

Comment: Searching for 2 hour and just found the method to kill multiple process at once. +1. Nice & clean

Comment: Killing nginx is not the best way to stop it: nginx generates several processes that monitor and restart each other to ensure fault tolerance. Using nginx.exe with the appropriate switches is the right solution.

Answer (score 53):

You can stop using `quit`

> `nginx.exe -s quit`

Comment: This is the way to do, and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

One can **toggle** Nginx *start stop* in Windows using 2 command prompts.  One for Nginx *start* and other for Nginx *Stop*.

If you stop Nginx from one command prompt then the Nginx process which was started from other prompt will **automatically** stop, Otherwise if you try to stop the Nginx process from where it started using **ctrl+c** then it will **not** stop even tough you close the command prompt, Unless you kill the nginx processes from TaskManager.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Starting nginx with `daemon off` will do the trick.

nginx is detauched from the console by default, independently if you run it directly using
`./nginx.exe`
or (as suggested by the guide) using
`start ./nginx.exe`

if you wanna stay coupled with the process who run the nginx (so it can pass the SIGTERM / CTRL+C to the nginx) you have to run this command:

`nginx -g "daemon off;"`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
wmic process where name='nginx.exe' delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a **.bat file** in the **nginx.exe** folder with the command: `nginx.exe -s quit`. Then make a shortcut to desktop or whereever needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in from this [site](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,241672,287412#msg-287412)

Below is the part that save my day!

```
(also maybe) Be sure to run as admin.
```

Once I run the Powershell as Administrator,

```
TASKKILL /F /IM nginx.exe
```

terminate them all and they never return.

I also realize "nginx-FMWS50.exe" at the task-manager which I don't know why.
What I did was I alter the same command to

```
TASKKILL /F /IM nginx_FMWS50.exe
```

BOOM! It works!

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the steps motioned below to quit or reload the nginx if facing any issue like.

nginx: [error] CreateFile() "...logs/nginx.pid" failed

(2: The system cannot find the file specified)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you run via docker, you can type something like this in a separate window:

```
docker system prune
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a windows shortcut somewhere and add the following in the target box:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "wmic process where name='nginx.exe' delete" && exit
```

Anytime you double clicked, nginx get shut down.